# This token doesn't work

Tags: flex-lexer

I don't understand why this token doesn't work. The token is this:
TEXT = [a-zA-Z0-9-_,;. \t\r\n\r\n]+

The token TEXT must recognize some text, with whitespace and new lines. For example the following token works:

TEXT = [a-zA-Z0-9-_,;. \t]+

How can i do to add the possibility of new lines in the token TEXT?

Comment: `\n` is a metacharacter for newlines, `\r` is for carriage return.

Comment: And so? What does it mean?

Comment: The 'flex' tag is for Adobe Flex. Did you mean 'flex-lexer'?

Comment: @user3640434 well guess what. you cam use it to have your regex recognize newlines, obviously.

Comment: Maybe someone needs an answer at this question. I found the correct regular expression for TEXT. It recognizes whitespace and new lines. 
TEXT= ((\r\n|\r|\n)*[a-zA-Z0-9\-_,;. \t](\r\n|\r|\n)*)*

Comment: If you have a seperate token rule `WHITE =[ \t\n\r]+` does that work to match 1 or more whitespace items?  Can you explain why you've added \r & \n twice into the char class?  BTW you might want \f, \b and \v as whitespace to (formfeeds, backspace, vertical tab).  Does char class help? [[:alnum:]-_,;.[:space:]] ?

Answer (score 0):

(Answered as a Community Wiki so that question shows an answer: See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

@user3640434 reported he found the correct regular expression for TEXT. It recognizes whitespace and new lines:

```
TEXT= ((\r\n|\r|\n)*[a-zA-Z0-9\-_,;. \t](\r\n|\r|\n)*)*
```

@Rob11311 Noted:

If you have a separate token rule `WHITE =[ \t\n\r]+` does that work to match 1 or more whitespace items? Can you explain why you've added `\r` & `\n` twice into the char class? BTW you might want `\f`, `\b` and `\v` as whitespace to (formfeeds, backspace, vertical tab). Does char class help? `[[:alnum:]-_,;.[:space:]]` ?